# How to find this polynomial chromatic function for this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I have this graph here picture[image]. And i tried to calculate this myself with removing an edge and contracting an edge here.
Below [image]

And i got my Polyomiak function to $\lambda*(\lambda-1)^{4}*(\lambda-2) - \lambda*(\lambda-1)^{3}*(\lambda-2)$ But that is not correct according to the answers because when i plug in 3 i get 24 but the correct answer they get in the answers section is 30 and they have PG to $ \lambda(\lambda − 1)(\lambda − 2)^{2}
(\lambda^2-2*\lambda+2)$ what have i done wrong here i don't really not know what i have done wrong in this question to get the correct chromatic polynomial right?

Comment: Your chromatic polynomial for the cycle graph is wrong, for the last vertex, there is not always $\lambda-2$ possibilities, you can have one more possibility if the two adjacent vertices are the same.

Comment: Also, it is a better strategy to split a graph along a cut separator when you can, this leads to much easier computation. Here, you can decompose along the edge that separates the triangle from the $C_5$

Comment: @caduk can you provide a solution please?

Answer (score 1):

The chromatic polynomial of a triangle is $\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)$.

It is well know that the chromatic polynomial of $C_k$ is $(\lambda-1)^k +(-1)^k(\lambda-1)$, so the chromatic polynomial of $C_5$ is $(\lambda-1)^5 +(-1)^5(\lambda-1) = (\lambda-1)((\lambda-1)^4 -1) = \lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)(\lambda^2-2\lambda+2)$ (factorization obtained by applying twice the standard identity.

To find the total number of coloring, we take the product, but we need to divide by $\lambda(\lambda-1)$ because the choice of a coloring for the triangle forces the colors of two vertices for the $C_5$, hence we get the correct result:
$$\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda^2-2\lambda+2)$$